# Can camcorder Sony HDR CX455 record videos in MP4 at 1920 x 1080i to be uploaded to YouTube?

Tags: video, mp4, video-recording, youtube, avchd

The specs of the camcorder Sony HDR CX455 states that it can record videos in the following formats:

1920 x 1080p at 24/30/60 fps (50 Mb/s XAVC S)

1440 x 1080i at 60 fps (5 Mb/s AVCHD)

1280 x 720p at 30 fps (3 Mb/s MP4)

It also says that "**The HDR-CX455 records 4K and HD movies in the XAVC S format, which uses MPEG-4 AVC/H.264 for video compression and linear PCM for audio compression, while saving files in a MP4 wrapper which allows for extensive record times and easy editing. Additionally, you can chose to record HD in AVCHD (ideal for HDTV and Blu-ray disc burning) or MP4 (ideal for sharing over the internet).**"

(Please note the part in the paragraph above that says "**MPEG-4**")

Now, unless I am mistaken, YouTube does not take the format **XAVC S** and **AVCHD**. Instead, YouTube does take the **MP4** format.

But, I don't want to use the format MP4 at 1280 x 720p, which is a low resolution.

If I use this camcorder, can I record videos in the **MP4 format at 1920 x 1080i** so that I can load the videos to YouTube ?

Thanks.

PS: The specs of  Sony HDR CX455 can be found at this link: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1211907-REG/sony_hdrcx455_b_hdr_cx455_full_hd_handycam.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the official answer from Sony Customer Service as follow:

**Yes, You can record MP4 at 1920 x 1080p. Please be advised that the video format for the XAVC S is in MP4, while the AVCHD is for m2ts files. And please make sure that the File Format that is set in your camcorder is XAVC S HD:
- Press Menu.
- Select Image Quality/ Size.
- File Format (film icon) and select  XAVC S HD.**

http://helpguide.sony.net/cam/1610/v1/en/contents/TP0000945876.html